# Disable / Enable Button with another button

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, button

I am building an app that generates teams with button selectors. The initial team is (available team) which has two buttons; the player name button which populates the player name into (alpha team), and the kick button which populates the player name into the (bench team).

What I would like to do is when the player name button is pushed it should disable the kick button; and when the kick button is pushed it should disable the player name button.

I've tried different methods but haven't gotten closer to a solution.
Help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const green = '#39D1B4';
const yellow = '#FFD712';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    let availableTeam = ['Benzo Walli', 'Rasha Loa', 'Tayshaun Dasmoto', 'Colmar Cumberbatch', 'Femi Billon', 'Ziya Erika', 'Siyabonga Nesta', 'Sylvain Natalie', 'Dipak Iunia', 'Danel Mio'];
    let alphaTeam = [];
    let omegaTeam = [];
    let benchTeam = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      const playerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableTeam.length);
      omegaTeam.push(availableTeam[playerIndex]);
      availableTeam.splice(playerIndex, 1);
    }
    this.state = {
     availableTeam : availableTeam,
     alphaTeam : [],
     omegaTeam : omegaTeam,
     benchTeam : []
    };
  }


  handleClick(player) {
    let newAlphaTeam = this.state.alphaTeam;
    // if player is not in array , add him
    if(newAlphaTeam.indexOf(player)<0){
        newAlphaTeam.push(player);
    }
    // if player is in the array , remove him
    else{
      newAlphaTeam.splice(newAlphaTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    //setState to rerender the App component
    this.setState({
      alphaTeam : newAlphaTeam,
    });
  }

  handleClickBench(player) {
    let newBenchTeam = this.state.benchTeam;
    // if player is not in array , add him
    if(newBenchTeam.indexOf(player)<0){
        newBenchTeam.push(player);
    }
    // if player is in the array , remove him
    else{
      newBenchTeam.splice(newBenchTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    //setState to rerender the App component
    this.setState({
      benchTeam : newBenchTeam,
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <h3>On the Bench</h3>
          {this.state.benchTeam.map((player, key) => <div key={key}><button>{player}</button></div>)}
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Available Team Members</h3>
          {this.state.availableTeam.map((player, key) => <div key={key}><button onClick={() => this.handleClick(player)}>{player}</button><button onClick={() => this.handleClickBench(player)}>Kick</button></div>)}
        </div>

        <div>
          <h3>Alpha Team Members</h3>
          {this.state.alphaTeam.map((player, key) => <div key={key}><button>{player}</button></div>)}
        </div>

        <div>
          <h3>Omega Team Members</h3>
          {this.state.omegaTeam.map((player, key) => <div key={key}><button>{player}</button></div>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button depending on if the player is already in the state array.

Example:

Player is in the bench team array. You want to disable the kick button:

```
// Kick button
<div key={key}>
    <button disabled={this.state.benchTeam.indexOf(player) !== -1}>Kick</button>
</div>
```

Player is in alphaTeam. You want to disable the player name button.

```
// Player button
<div key={key}>
    <button disabled={this.state.alphaTeam.indexOf(player) !== -1}>{player}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below meets your requirement. I have taken two Boolean state variables. When you push player button change kickButtonDisabled to true like wise when you push kick button change playerNameButtonDisabled to true in handler functions. Finally add the states to button disabled attribute.

```
this.state = {
   playerNameButtonDisabled: false,
   kickButtonDisabled: false
}

handleClick(player) {
    let newAlphaTeam = this.state.alphaTeam;
    // if player is not in array , add him
    if(newAlphaTeam.indexOf(player)<0){
        newAlphaTeam.push(player);

        //disable kick button
        this.setState({
          kickButtonDisabled: true,
          playerNameButtonDisabled: false
        })

    }
    // if player is in the array , remove him
    else{
      newAlphaTeam.splice(newAlphaTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    //setState to rerender the App component
    this.setState({
      alphaTeam : newAlphaTeam,
    });
  }

handleClickBench(player) {
    let newBenchTeam = this.state.benchTeam;
    // if player is not in array , add him
    if(newBenchTeam.indexOf(player)<0){
        newBenchTeam.push(player);

        //Disable player name button
        this.setState({
          playerNameButtonDisabled: true,
          kickButtonDisabled: false
        });

    }
    // if player is in the array , remove him
    else{
      newBenchTeam.splice(newBenchTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    //setState to rerender the App component
    this.setState({
      benchTeam : newBenchTeam,
    });
  }

<button disabled={this.state.playerNameButtonDisabled} onClick={() => this.handleClick(player)}>{player}</button>
<button disabled={this.state.kickButtonDisabled} onClick={() => this.handleClickBench(player)}>Kick</button>
```

Hope this helps your requirement.